# Ajax Output not change after the passing id changeed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#get_mem_det").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_mem_detil.php",
            data: { id: $("#HMID").val() },
            success: function(result) {
                $("#resl").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```php
<?php
    $sql_view = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member_tb WHERE u_id <> '$userid' AND status='' ORDER BY mem_id ASC ");
    while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_view)) {
        <input id="HMID" name="HMID" type="hidden" value="'.$res['mem_id'].'" />'; ?>
        <input type="button" id="get_mem_det" value="View" class="btn btn-small"  onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" >
    <?php  } ?>

<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Click Me To Close</a>
    <div id="resl"></div>
</div>
```

The AJAX is working fine. but `#HMID` POST value won't change while requesting to the `get_mem_detil.php`, so the same result is coming for each and every button click. How can I resolve it?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the value of `#HMID` is changed before sending the request? What is its value? Are there more than one elements with the id of `HMID`?

Comment: yes the #HMID is value is coming from the DB, and there are more than one elements.

Comment: If you want to update html(like this  `$("#resl").html(result);`) from `AJAX` request, you should `echo` or `print_r()` on the server side.

Comment: i have echo the request but the output is same

Comment: `there are more than one elements` There is your problem. You have duplicate `id` attributes, when they *must* be unique within the page. Change the `#HMID` to a class and it should work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how to change to a class

Comment: I've added an answer for you, explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#get_mem_det").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_mem_detil.php",
            data: { id: $("#HMID").val() },
            success: function(result) {
                $("#resl").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Will always be taking the first input field with the id of HMID, you should onclick with the button call a function(this.form), and then in the function get the value of the hidden field by doing this:

```
function func(form) {
    var HMID = form.elements['HMID'].value;
    $("#get_mem_det").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "get_mem_detil.php",
            data: { id:HMID},
            success:function(result)
            {
                $("#resl").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And the just send the HMID variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are appending multiple elements with the same `id` attribute to the page - `id` must be unique. This then means that whenever you select the `#HMID` element, only the first one is found which makes it appear as though the value never changes. Try changing to use a class instead:

```
<?php
    $sql_view = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member_tb WHERE u_id <> '$userid' AND status='' ORDER BY mem_id ASC ");
    while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_view)) { ?>
        <input class="HMID" name="HMID" type="hidden" value="'<? echo $res['mem_id'] ?>'" />'; 
        <input type="button" id="get_mem_det" value="View" class="btn btn-small"  onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">
<?php  } ?>
```

From there you can traverse to find the input in the button click handler:

```
$("#get_mem_det").click(function(){
    var hmidVal = $(this).prev('.HMID').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_mem_detil.php",
        data: { id: hmidVal },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#resl").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: after changing from id to class the same output is printed